# Simplify the average value of a product of matrices

Tags: matrices, random-matrices, unitary-matrices

I want to compute the average of a product of random matrices:

$$\langle R^\dagger A R \rangle $$

where $R$ and $A$ are uncorrelated $3\times3$ random unitary matrices (with $\dagger$ the conjugate transpose).

After some numerical tests it seems that this simplifies to $\langle A  \rangle$. Is this true in general, and is there a simple way to prove it?

Comment: What is the meaning of the symbol $<>$?

Comment: Expectation, I suppose.

Comment: An easy observation is that since they are uncorrelated, $<R^\dagger A R>=<R^\dagger <A>R>$., that is, you can average over A directly.

Comment: I can't be true in general, if $A,R$ are constant then they are independent and it is not tru in general that $A=R^*AR$.